# Stream Images using a local server

Tags: javascript, php, html, apache

I want to stream images (print screens of the server) using a local server (apache). For an example i will go to the website using a machine on the same network and then this web site will show me set of images at a speed around 30fps (then i will see it as a video). The image quality has to be good.

At the moment i can go to this website using a machine connected to local network. But i cannot figure out a way to **stream images**. And I have no knowledge of PHP..

Is this possible to achieve??

Can anyone point me in the right direction...

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you rather use ffmpeg to create a video from the images? 
Check : https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer...
These images are not pre-available. I need to take a screen shot and send it to the client at every, say 40ms. So it would be like a real time video.. That is my issue..

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg can help you create videos from images. It has a cli binary that can do the task.

Ref: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... These images are not pre-available. I need to take a screen shot and send it to the client at every, say 40ms. So it would be like a real time video.. That is my issue.. So is it possible to do that with ffmpeg?

Thank you